# Swiping from top to bottom on mobile doesn't work (hammer js)

Tags: angular, hammer.js

I am using hammerjs in my angular app. I have on the main page carousel of images, which I can swipe on left and on right. Also I have a fixed header, when I click on my hamburger button, menu is opened and I want to swipe it from bottom to top.
So now I cannot swipe from top to bottom on my main page. Swiping on carousel works, swiping on header also.
I tried to comment my component of carousel on my main page and swiping works good, when I swipe on top. 
How can I fixed it?

```
export class HammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
    public overrides: Record<string, {}> = {
        pinch: { enable: false },
        rotate: { enable: false },
        swipe: { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL },
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class MyHammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
  events: string[] = [];

  overrides: {[key: string]: Object} = {};

  buildHammer(element: HTMLElement): HammerInstance {
    return new Hammer(element, {
      cssProps: Hammer.defaults.cssProps,
      recognizers: [
        [Hammer.Swipe],
        [Hammer.Tap],
      ],
    });
  }
}
```

in MyComponent.ts

```
const hammerConfig = new HtcHammerConfig()
    const hammer = hammerConfig.buildHammer(document.documentElement)

    fromEvent(hammer, "swipe").pipe(
      takeWhile(()=>this.alive))
      .subscribe((res: any) => {

        console.log(res.deltaY<0?'to the top':'to the bottom'  )
      });
```